# Angular Universal using global browser objects like window and localstorage

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

My rather large Angular Universal app needs to use the local storage and window object. Node.js doesnt use those objects and I get a reference error of either window or localstorage is not defined.

I know I can use the `IsPlatformBrowser` module but I would have to add to the conditional state for this all over the app ( a few hundred places) and future uses.

Is there something I could write that just goes over the entire project on the node server or on the client?

Comment: You can wrap the localstorage in a function that checks for `IsPlatformBrowser`

Comment: Like a service? Are you saying replace all localstorage, window objects with a function from a service?

Comment: Yup, wrap them in a service as functions, and add `IsPlatformBrowser` inside the functions

Comment: Universal must not execute any code that has `window` or `localstorage`, otherwise it will throw an error

Comment: The issue is replacing all the old code which is everywhere. Do I just have to refactor or is there a way to define the global objects so I don't have to refactor?

Comment: @MurhafSousli Do you know of any node.js solutions?

Comment: You probably need to refactor, alternatively you can use some angular localstorage library on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making a file for the global objects. In the file I have two services I use `LocalStorageService` and `WindowService`. I had to refactor quite a bit of code but I couldn't find a better solution for this. Works flawlessly now with Angular Universal.

Luckily `localStorage` is a simple browser api with only 5 functions and one property so i could write the whole thing out. However `window` has dozens of functions and properties, meaning Ill have to write the function in the `WindowService` before using it else where.

Its rather inelegant but it works.

Heres my global objects file:

```
  import { Injectable, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})



export class LocalStorageService {
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

    clear() {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            localStorage.clear();
        }
    }

    setItem(key: string, value: string) {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        }
    }

    getItem(key: string) {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
           return localStorage.getItem(key);
        }
    }

    removeItem(key: string) {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }

    key(index: number) {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            return localStorage.key(index);
        }
    }

    length() {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            return localStorage.length;
        }
    }


}

export class WindowService {
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

    scrollTo(x: number , y: number) {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
         window.scrollTo(x, y);
        }
    }    

    open(url?: string, target?: string, feature?: string, replace?: boolean) {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        window.open(url, target, feature, replace);
        }
    }

}
```